# I am creating a pipe to filter curse words, need assistance

Tags: angular, pipe

I am using a package called Bad-Words in angular project, and created a custom pipe using this. This pipe works perfect on chrome, but the code breaks in IE 11. The complete UI goes blank , figured out that there is some syntax error in javascript file.

Here I extracted the code from that .js file and optimized the code, and wrote it in the custom Pipe itself. 
Now I won't get the desired output

Sample input : `"I will Kill you "`

Desired o/p : `"I will **** you"`

Any help is appreciated

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core'; 

@Pipe({
    name: 'appProfanityFilter'
})
export class ProfanityFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {


    list = ["Kill", "5h1t", "5hit", "a55", .........  "xxx"];
    placeHolder: '*';
    regex: '/[^a-zA-Z0-9|\$|\@]|\^/g';
    replaceRegex: '/\w/g';

    transform(value: string) {
        if (value === undefined || value === '') {
            return '';
        }

        return this.clean(value);
    }


    isProfane(string) {
        debugger;
        const result = this.list
            .filter((word) => {
                const wordExp = new RegExp(`\\b${word.replace(/(\W)/g, '\\$1')}\\b`, 'gi');
                return wordExp.test(string);
            })
            .length > 0 || false;
        return result;
    }

    replaceWord(string) {
        debugger;
        const result = string
            .replace(this.regex, '')
            .replace(this.replaceRegex, this.placeHolder);
        return result;
    }

    clean(string) {
        debugger;
        const result = string.split(/\b/).map((word) => {
            return this.isProfane(word) ? this.replaceWord(word) : word;
        }).join('');

        return result;
    }
}
```

I will be using this pipe throughout the code.

`somedata = "I will kill you"`

eg. `<span> {{somedata | appProfanityFilter}} </span>`

expected O/p: `I will **** you`

I am using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bad-words)  Package

Comment: You are using some functions that are not supported by IE 11, if you open your console in IE11 you should see errors

Comment: Where's the error (and which line causes it)?

Comment: Is it working without this pipe?

Comment: @TheHeadRush Console shows nothing, but when I try to debug, console shows a syntax error at the start of Filter Class , from  "https://www.npmjs.com/package/bad-words " package

Comment: @youri This pipe works perfectly fine, when I run my code in Chrome, but breaks in IE, dont know why !

Comment: @ChetanBirajdar, yes but is your app working on IE without this pipe?

Comment: @youri Yes it works, without this pipe, ...
This is how I was using the pipe, ....
    transform(value: string) {
        if (value === undefined || value === '') {
            return '';
        }
        const filter = new Filter(); 
        return filter.clean(value); 
    }.....Turns out this does work fine in chrome... but the UI breaks in IE...The other code mentioned above in the question is which I have took from the JavaScript of the package

Answer (score 1):

I figured out there was syntax problem in regex function. 
What I did is removed the code inside the method replaceWord(string) by `filter.inner(string)`

for this I added a package called [f-ck](https://www.npmjs.com/package/f-ck), to mask the curse words (which are declared in 'list' array) in a sentence.

Now: if my input is : "I will kill you"
output will be "I will k**l you"

This pipe can be used further, anywhere in the code. 
eg. 
somedata = "I will kill you"

{{somedata | appProfanityFilter}}